# from fixed hight to auto on hover

Tags: html, css

I want to have some text revealed on hover from a fixed height to the full height of the child, but can't seem to make it work.

Here is the snippet:

```css
.c1 {
    width: 50%;
    max-height: 100px;
    background: red;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition: max-height 4s ease-in;
}

.c1:hover {
    max-height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="c1">
  <div style="width:auto;height;300px">
    text text text text text text 
    texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext 
    text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text 
    texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext 
    text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text 
    texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext 
    text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text 
    texttext text texttext text text
</div>
  </div>
```

I would like the red area to expand downward slowly to reveal the rest of the text. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can't animate to `auto` in CSS

Comment: @Christine Braun max-height has no `auto` value. Please check my answer http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-height.asp

Comment: @christine I'm added an answer ,check is that is usefull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that there is no value `auto` for max-height.

What are you looking for is `max-height: none`,  however is not animatable. To animate this transition you have to give it an specific height.

Change your Css hover class to this if you

```
.c1:hover {
    /* No Animation*/
    max-height: none;
}
```

or

```
.c1:hover {
    /* With Animation*/
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

Here is Chris Coyier from CSS Tricks talking about it. https://css-tricks.com/css-animate-fromto-auto/

Now, you really should not use inline CSS and Linked CSS. And there is some redundant code, as for example you don't need the inline css you added at all.

Comment: the extra `<div>` was by mistake, copied and pasted somewhere else. Since height won't animate is there anyway to get what I want, that the red box expands downward slowly to reveal all the text?

Comment: Well is the height of the div dynamic or  the div will have a max-height?. If dynamic you need Javascript. I added an update to my answer

Comment: yes the height is dynamic, which is why i was trying to use `auto`. So there is no way to do this if the height is dynamic with just CSS then?

Comment: @ChristineBraun if you go to the link given by Chris Collyer, you'll see that there is a hack to allow what you want with pure CSS.  Just add max-height: `a value bigger than the max value of your div will ever have`. However the transition back is kind of funny if the value is way to big

Comment: Ok I think i will just use the workaround for now. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change few lines in css and html.

```css
.c1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition: max-height 4s ease-in;
}

.c1:hover {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="c1">
  <div >
    text text text text text text 
    texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext 
    text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text 
    texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext 
    text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text 
    texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext 
    text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text 
    texttext text texttext text text
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.c1 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition: max-height 4s ease-in;
}

.c1:hover {
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="c1">
  <div style="width:auto;height;300px">
    text text text text text text 
    texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext 
    text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text 
    texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext 
    text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text 
    texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext 
    text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text 
    texttext text texttext text text
</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

put **height** instead of **max-height**. it will works fine,I'm added the snippet below

```css
.c1 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition:height 4s ease-in;
}

.c1:hover {
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="c1">
  <div style="width:auto;height;300px">
    text text text text text text 
    texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext 
    text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text 
    texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext 
    text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text 
    texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext 
    text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text 
    texttext text texttext text text
</div>
  </div>
```

you can **speed up** the transition by **adjusting the transition duration**

```css
.c1 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition:height 0.5s ease-in;
}

.c1:hover {
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="c1">
  <div style="width:auto;height;300px">
    text text text text text text 
    texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext 
    text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text 
    texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext 
    text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text 
    texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext 
    text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text 
    texttext text texttext text text
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Yes this works but it is not animated. Any way to get the desired animation of the red box slowly expanding?

Comment: @ChristineBraun because you give the property **transition:height 4s ease-in;** so it's **transition duration** is **4s** ,you can adjust that to speed up the transition

Comment: @ChristineBraun I think you didn't check the snippet ,please run the snippet it's working fine.

Comment: this seems to only work if you put a fixed height in the hover (does not work with `height=auto`), so there is no way to make this responsive, if the page size changes then so will the pixels needed to reveal all the text.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your css with this

```
.c1 {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    background: red;
    overflow:hidden;

}


.expand{
  height:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition: height 4s ease-in;
}

.expand:hover {
    height: auto;
    transition: height 4s ease-in;
}
```

And HTML

```
<div class="c1">
  <div class="expand">
    text text text text text text 
    texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext 
    text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text 
    texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext 
    text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text 
    texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext 
    text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text 
    texttext text texttext text text
</div>
  </div>
```

If you Animate on Mouseover, You can set a fixed height property to `.expand:hover`

Working Demo https://jsfiddle.net/Rahul_Ravi/Lvecptnx/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.c1 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition:height 4s ease-in;
}
.c1:hover {
    height: 250 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="c1">
  <div style=" width:auto;">
   Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample  Sample 
</div>
  </div>
```

```css
.c1 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition:height 4s ease-in;
}
.c1 div{
  width:auto;
}
.c1:hover {
    height: auto;
    transition:height 4s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="c1">
  <div>
    text text text text text text 
    texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext 
    text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text 
    texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext 
    text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text 
    texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext 
    text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text 
    texttext text texttext text text
</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Few changes in css and remove inline css from html. You must need define **specific height** for css animation on hover function.

```css
.c1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 1s ease-in;
}
.c1:hover {
 height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="c1">
  <div>
    text text text text text text 
    texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext 
    text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text 
    texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext 
    text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text 
    texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext 
    text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text 
    texttext text texttext text text
  </div>
</div>
```